# how to only detect person class from yolov8?

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, face-detection

I want to detect only person class from yolov8 that also one person could anybody tell how?

i dont find any thing in docs .i want to crop only first person and to put it in classification model.

Answer (score 6):

The following code does what you want.

```
pip install ultralytics
```

```
$ python3
>>> from ultralytics import YOLO
>>> model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
Downloading https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v0.0.0/yolov8n.pt to yolov8n.pt...
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6.23M/6.23M [00:09<00:00, 685kB/s]
>>> results = model("zidane.jpg")

image 1/1 /home/.../zidane.jpg: 384x640 2 persons, 1 tie, 7.9ms
Speed: 0.7ms preprocess, 7.9ms inference, 0.9ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
>>> results = model("zidane.jpg", classes=0)

image 1/1 /home/.../zidane.jpg: 384x640 2 persons, 5.7ms
Speed: 0.3ms preprocess, 5.7ms inference, 2.5ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

Just add the argument `classes=` as said [here](https://docs.ultralytics.com/usage/cfg/#prediction) in the documentation.

You will get the bounding box from the inference output and can crop your image using that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can get only one person to track but for detecting only people:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from ultralytics.utils.plotting import Annotator

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
model.classes = [0]
```

This worked for me.